# Django render_to_response displaying raw text

Tags: django

I am new to Django and I'm trying to create a simple html skeleton to verify everything is working properly. Everything is working (server is running and it loads the file) yet when I put in HTML code it is displayed as raw text instead of rendering it correctly.

My views.py is as follows

```
def home(request):
        return render_to_response('index.html')
```

My 'index.html' is as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html >

    <html>
        <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title> awesome </title>
        </head>
        <body>
      
        </body>
    </html>
```

What should I do to have it render correctly? (Display only "awesome")

EDIT 
As far as this problem goes, the error came in that I saved the raw code as html. When I chose this option, it added the code to make html render it look like a raw input.

Moral of the story: Make sure you do your edits in a text editor and change extension by hand

Answer (score 2):

A few problems..

1: what's with the spaces inside your tags?

`< title >` is invalid. It needs to be `<title>Foo</title>` That's why you're seeing "html".

2: Even if the title tag was written correctly, a title tag does not render, so you will get a blank page. If you want to display "awesome" -- you need to write it inside the body tag.

```
<body>awesome</body>
```

Comment: Seems like copy/paste from some kindle books delivers up the html with spaces all through it.

Answer (score 2):

1) Remove spaces in < title > tag

2) And add bellow code in your urls.py file no need to map with view you can render html page from url also

```
 (r'^home/$', 'django.views.generic.simple.direct_to_template',
        {'template': 'index.html'}),
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is create a "base" template so the other templates can extend from. You will normally call it `base.html` but you can use the name you want. You also need to create `blocks` that extended templates can use:

**base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html >

<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
        < title > awesome < /title >
    </head>
    <body>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Then, you have to extend `base.html` from your `index.html` and use the `content` block we have created:

**index.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

At this point, `index.html` will be exactly as `base.html` because you are not showing anything inside the `content` block. Update your view with some data like this:

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
    data = {'name': 'YourName', 'age': 25}

    return render_to_response('index.html', data)
```

Now, again, update your `index.html`:

**index.html**

```
{% extends "base.html"%}

{% block content %}
    <p>My name is {{ name }}</p>
    <p>I'm {{ age }} years old</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Don't forget to read the fine [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/).